# Word that means "spoken so as to make clear there is no arguing"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've tried "asking" Google this question in multiple ways, as well as using a reverse dictionary, but niether of those came close to being useful. I've seen this word several times, particularly In Ann McCaffrey's Pern novels, and believe it starts with a "C". It essentially means that something was said in such a way that the other parties to the conversation know that there is no room question or argue with the speaker.

A sample would be "We were playing pool all night," Tom $WORD to Dick when Officer Harry questioned them as to where they were at the time they murdered that one guy.

A key part of the definition is that the speaker is trying to silence any potential opposition before it is spoken. So it isn't just that Tom is speaking with authority, but also that he is denying Dick the right to disagree, or make any alteration to Tom's statement. It's as if there are the unspoken words "and that is the end of that" appended to the speaker's message.

That's probably not the the proper way to use the word. I see these words, and months or years later come to a situation where I want to use say something while using just the right word. However, I don't know what that is much of the time and I rack my brain until it gives me something that I can put into a dictionary. Unfortunately, my brain is being non-compliant.

Comment: Confirm(ed)? And the novles are Pern, not Parn.

Comment: No, "confirmed" isn't the correct word. The definition explicit states that the word indicates that what is being said is the not to be questioned or argued with. It should be somewhere in the Merriam Websters dictionary.

Also, thank you for calling me out on the spelling of the Novel. I can't help but think of the protagonist in Record of Lodoss Wars. Particularly the terrible dubbing where the sorcerer says "Parn...get in...there". That was the day I decided I would learn to read subtitles.

Comment: _asserted_ You'll probably just have to reread the novels and find it yourself.

Comment: I fear you are correct.

Comment: I know you just asked for one word. I'd just like to provide an alternative: "We were playing pool all night," Tom said to Dick in a tone of voice that brooked no argument, when Officer Harry questioned them as to where they were at the time they murdered that one guy.

Comment: Tom is *compelling* Dick to adhere to his version of events - is that your word?

Answer (score 1):

[**Contend**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/contend?s=t) has a meaning of *to assert or maintain earnestly* . Also, although it doesn't start with C the word **asserted** would be suitable as well.

Comment: Contend doesn't carry with it the assumption that the speaker is trying to quash dissent before it is spoken. Same goes for "assert".

Comment: @Nerogris - There is [corroborate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corroborate) which is like a further validation of an existing assertion, though it doesn't pertain to quashing dissent either.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question again, although there are a few words that come to mind, such as conclude (as already suggested by [Nihal](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/404754/124936)) and convince (which incidentally enough has an etymological relation to vanquish), the only one that makes much sense to me in your provided context is the word *[Confirm](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/confirm)*, with the following definitions from An American Dictionary of the English Language (A.D.E.L.) by Noah Webster:

> 3. To make firm or certain; to give new assurance of truth or certainty; to put past doubt.
>
> > The testimony of Christ was confirmed in you. 1 Corinthians 1:8.

Putting a claim past doubt seems to match the described concept. However in your provided context this definition is not the one that actually makes much sense. I'd rather think that this meaning makes more sense:

> 6. To make more firm; to strengthen; as, to confirm an opinion, a purpose or resolution. — A.D.E.L.

And one of the ways this is often done is by reiterating what was already said, especially if you are verifying the words of another person. Hence the following definition of the word [Confirm](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=confirm&oldid=47029303) excerpted from Wiktionary:

> 3. To assure the accuracy of previous statements.

Which probably uses the following definition of the word [Assure](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=assure&oldid=46126741), which is also excerpted from Wiktionary:

> 2. (transitive, followed by that or of) To give (someone) confidence in the trustworthiness of (something). [[All Wiktionary text is licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0 terms](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)]

It makes quite a fair amount of sense in the context of being questioned by the police, who often make inquiries to the the truth behind allegations, and need evidence such as the verification of witnesses to do so effectively.

Compare your provided context:

> "We were playing pool all night," Tom [confirmed] to Dick when Officer Harry questioned them as to where they were at the time they murdered that one guy.

To these quotations:

> Before she got into the car she said, "Officer, please, he didn't do anything. I blocked his car in so I can get him in trouble. Please, Officer, don't take him to jail. He's the only person I got that will take care of my girl. Please, Officer, everything, it was me. Ask her. Tashelle, tell him y'all was trying to leave, and I pulled my car  in to block y'all from leaving." I confirmed to the officer that what she was saying was true, but I didn't think it would make a difference. But the female officer was quite understanding; she uncuffed Tony and told him that he was lucky. — [From Behind This Chair by Sarahca Peterson, p. 86 ©2010](https://books.google.com/books?id=HgN5-qCQQH0C&pg=PA86&dq=%22I+confirmed+to+the+officer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy1PWIxsfVAhXKrlQKHdzKBNgQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Shortly after Mrs. Snake's funeral, I received a call from a police officer. I was in the kitchen when the call came and I knew to sit down. When I confirmed to the officer that Ryan was my brother, he explained that Ryan had passed. He had taken his own life, hanging himself in a homeless shelter two days after his birthday; he died a mere fourty-five minutes from where I attended school.
>
> ---
>
> [My Fields of Everything](https://books.google.com/books?id=wZ5fDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT133&dq=%22I%20confirmed%20to%20the%20officer%22&pg=PT133#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Angelika Crescenzi ©2014

Granted, Dick is not an officer in your context, but the common theme here is the verification of another party's express or implicit report. In your case, I suppose Dick heard the allegations from the police officer and requested confirmation from Tom. Also, as long as I have mentioned it, I may as well give some of A.D.E.L's. definitions of [Confirmation](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/confirmation):

> 4. The act of giving new evidence; as the confirmation of opinion or report.
>   5. That which confirms; that which gives new strength or assurance; additional evidence; proof; convincing testimony; as, this fact or this argument is a confirmation of what was before alleged.

Part of my apprehension to these other options I considered earlier, given this sentence, is twofold: One is that it is not entirely clear to me that the other options quite so often mean to actually say anything, and the other is that it would be odd to follow them with the word *To [somebody]*. [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confirmed+to+him%2Cconcluded+to+him%2Cconvinced+to+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconfirmed%20to%20him%3B%2Cc0) suggests that *concluded to him* and *convinced to him* simply never occur in written English, whereas *confirmed to him* does show at least some results, despite a drastically decreasing frequency in overall usage:

[image]

However, this doubt is predicated on the assumption that your given context accurately reflects what is wanted, which is not certain to me since you are trying to recollect another person's words, and there are cases where *concluded to* would be used so I have not entirely ruled it out as an option. However, that is a suggestion for another answer to make. This one suggests *Confirm*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the word **definitively** .  While it can be used to describe a proof, if you applied the word in a way that characterized the manner of speech, I think it works the way you want it.

> [**definitively** at Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/definitively)
>   ADVERB
>
> Decisively and with authority; conclusively.
>
> *‘the benefits of this therapy have never been definitively proven’*
>
> *‘only a large clinical trial can definitively answer the question’*

You'll notice that those two examples do not use it to describe tone of speech, but my example would be:

*He said definitively, "I've decided that our team colors will be blue and white." then moved on to the next item of discussion on the meeting agenda.*

In your sentence:

"We were playing pool all night," Tom __ said definitively __ to Dick when Officer Harry questioned them as to where they were at the time they murdered that one guy.

(although, to use definitively more naturally, I might change the sentence to:

.... *Tom told Dick definitively when Officer* ...

"Autocratically" might be used in similar way ... although it is a bit formal for your example sentence.

> [**autocratic** at Oxford Living dictionaries.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/autocratic)
>
> 1.1 Taking no account of other people's wishes or opinions; domineering.
>   ‘a man with a reputation for an autocratic management style’

Comment: That is a good one since it has a tone of authority. However it doesn't carry with it the preemptive quashing of dissent that the word I'm looking for has.

Comment: You could try using "autocratically" -- I'll include the definition above.

Comment: It does have much the same function, but with a different flavor. In the case of F'lare, in the Pern novels, it would be most appropriate since he was an autocrat, but that was not the word used. This is more like a itch I'm trying to scratch at this point. Originally I had wanted it for an amateur fiction piece I've been working occationally, but due to the changes to the narrative structure used to convey that part of the story, it is neither needed nor wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word you are seeking is ***concur***.

**Tom *concurred* with Dick, when questioned about the murder**.

Comment: No. That would mean that there exists nothing for which Dick would argue with or question. So what I'm looking for is form of assertion of fact as opposed to an acknowledgement of fact.

Answer (score 0):

Would that be *to **[conclude](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conclude)***?

It can mean *to bring to a decision or settlement; settle or arrange finally*, which is pretty much what you're describing.

Comment: [I was just about to suggest this myself, alongside the word close](http://archive.is/KYH4B), but I think it can be done much better than this. Would you mind if I gutted your answer and improved it to bring it more in line with the type of collaboration I believe this website normally seeks? I think it'll make it much clearer that this is probably the right word, which is probably more important than the rep. to me. Trust me when I say, I can make this answer much more convincing, interesting and conclusive, but I need the time to be able to do so, which I now don't have otherwise.

Comment: @Tonepoet I don't mind at all! More information is always welcome.